# comparing and removing rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, match, row

I am trying to create a new object by comparing two list. If the rows are matching the row should be removed form the splitted row_list or appended to a new list containing only the differences between both lists.

```
results = []
for row in splitted_row_list:
    print(row)
    for row1 in all_rows:
        if row1 == row:
            
            splitted_row_list.remove(row)
        else:
            results.append(row)





print(results)
```

However, this code just returns all the rows. Does anyone have a suggestion?
Sample data

```
all_rows[0]:'1390', '139080', '13980', '1380', '139080', '13080'
splitted_row_list[0]:'35335','53527','353529','242424','5222','444'
```

Comment: Can you include some sample data for `all_rows` and `splitted_row_list` ? And please also post the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to compare two lists by index and keep the differences and you want to do it with pandas (because of the tag):

So here are two lists for example:

```
ls1=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
ls2=[0,15,20,35,40,55,60,75,80,95]
```

I make a pandas dataframe with these lists, and build a mask to filter out the the matching values:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data={'ls1':ls1, 'ls2':ls2})
mask= df['ls1']!=df['ls2']
```

I can then call the different values for each list using the mask:

```
# list 1
df[mask]['ls1'].values

out: array([10, 30, 50, 70, 90])
```

and

```
# list 2
df[mask]['ls2'].values

out: array([15, 35, 55, 75, 95])
```